# iptables: Rate too fast Error

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, linux-kernel

I want to set hard limit for incoming UDP packets on my Linux machine which is inside 10 Gigabit LAN.

Following command works fine

```
/sbin/iptables -A UDP-LIMIT -m limit --limit 10000/s --limit-burst 500 -j RETURN
```

But when I try to increase limit like

```
/sbin/iptables -A UDP-LIMIT -m limit --limit 10001/s --limit-burst 500 -j RETURN
```

It gives me the error `Rate too fast`.

Any idea why?

I also saw a macro `#define XT_LIMIT_SCALE 10000 in`linux/netfilter/xt_limit.h` in linux kernel source.

Any idea why this limit is set?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source file `libxt_limit.c`, you can find the answer. Specifically, look at these lines in `parse_rate` function:

```
    *val = XT_LIMIT_SCALE * mult / r;
    if (*val == 0)
            /*
             * The rate maps to infinity. (1/day is the minimum they can
             * specify, so we are ok at that end).
             */
            xtables_error(PARAMETER_PROBLEM, "Rate too fast \"%s\"\n", rate);
    return 1;
```

The macro `XT_LIMIT_SCALE` is 10,000 as you said. The value of `mult` starts from 1 for seconds and reaches 24*60*60 for days. The largest value will be the case of days of course. If you do the math, you will get the following expression:

```
10000 * 24 * 60 * 60 / 10000 = 864,000,000 / 10000 = ..
```

The number to be divided can be stored in 32-bit unsigned integer (uint32_t). However, this number will be truncated if it becomes larger (like the case of XT_LIMIT_SCALE = 100,0000). The value `10001` will not cause this problem, but I think it is not useful value.

Comment: So if modify **XT_LIMIT_SCALE** to **100,000**, I will be able to extend per second limit beyond 10000 upto 100,000, right ?

Comment: @techiek7: No, you can't because this will cause the issue described in my answer above.